# python3 tkinter and matplot conflict

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a floating point slider with tkinter. After I import matplotlib.py the sliders stop working. Does anybody have an idea for why that is? Thank you for your help.
PS I'm new to stack so i wasn't sure how to format the code below, sorry for that.

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
#from functools import partial
#import pygame as pg
#import numpy as np
#import sympy as sym
#import mpmath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
#from pn import *
from gui import *

Panel_bczony_width=205

_width=1200
_height=800
zakres_gora      =[50 ,30,200,7,1000,1000,360,100]
zakres_dol       =[1  ,1,1  ,3,   1,1   ,330,  1]

class Parametry_ukladu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.pom=Label(self.master, text="Parametry Układu", width=25)
        self.pom.pack()
        self.scale=[]
        self.frame=[]
        self.label=[]
        self.pom=0
        for x in range(8):
            self.frame.append(Frame(self.master))
            self.label.append(Label( self.frame[x],  width=10))           
            #self.scale.append(Scale( self.frame[x], from_=zakres_dol[x], to=zakres_gora[x], orient=HORIZONTAL, command=lambda x: set_zmienne(self.scale, x)))
            self.scale.append(Scale( self.frame[x], from_=1.0, to=100.0, orient=HORIZONTAL, resolution=0.1))

            #self.scale[x].set(default_values[x])        
            self.label[x].pack(side=LEFT)            
            self.scale[x].pack(side=RIGHT)
            self.frame[x].pack(side=TOP)
#wczytaj("domyslne_dane.txt")
root = Tk()
parametry_u = Parametry_ukladu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

edit. I have found here:[Tkinter Matplotlib, backend conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789777/tkinter-matplotlib-backend-conflict) that changeing backend of matplotlib should solve the problem. To do that i call sth. like that:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WxAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But then when I try to use for example plt.plot() i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/plebania/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2355, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/home/plebania/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 221, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/plebania/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_wxagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'
```

Comment: You should avoid importing *, here are the reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Comment: I've changed tkinter import to import tkinter as tk but the behavior is unchanged

Comment: If you are otherwise using Tkinter in your program, you probably want to use the Tkinter backend for matplotlib - `TkAgg`, I think.

Comment: jasonharper Thanks that was a case :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing all * imports before debugging this. You could try one-by-one until you find which one exactly causes the issue.
What does "stopped working" mean ? Are the sliders still displayed ? Can you move them with mouse / keyboard ? Do they respond to other events ?

Comment: I've already done it. I commented all imports, but matplotlib.pyplot, and changed tkinter import to import tkinter as tk. No results. Adding matplotlib.use('WxAgg') supricely solves the problem, but then I don't know how to use matplotlib plots...